# Dimension of the nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the real vector space whose elements are the polynomials of degree $\leq 4$. and let $W=\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(f)=\begin{pmatrix} f(2)\\ f'(2)\end{pmatrix}$, where $f'$ denotes the derivative. I need to determine the $\dim(\ker(T))$

I think $\dim(\operatorname{ker}(T))=3\, \,\text{since}\, \dim(V)=5 \,\text{and}\, \dim(\operatorname{Im}(T))=2$

Comment: Are you able to prove that $\dim(im(T))=2$? Did you find its base?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\;\binom ab\in\Bbb R^2\;$ be any element , then with $\;f(x):=b(x-2)+a\;$ we get that

$$f(2)=a\;,\;\;f'(2)=b\implies T(f)=\binom ab\implies \dim\text{Im}\,f=2$$

and the map is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Saying $f\in\ker T$ means that $f(2)=f'(2)=0$, which means $f$ is divisible by $(x-2)^2$.

Every polynomial in $V$ can be written as

$$
a_0 + a_1(x-2) + a_2(x-2)^2 + a_3(x-2)^3 + a_4(x-2)^4
$$

(Taylor) so the condition becomes $a_0=a_1=0$. So a basis for the kernel is $\{(x-2)^2,(x-2)^3,(x-2)^4\}$.